# How to replace HTTP with a simple string in angular.js?

Tags: angularjs

I am started to work with Angular.js, I want to replace `HTTP://` of any URL in a simple string like 'hey', I didn't get any relevant solution.
I'd be grateful for your response.

Comment: Why do you try to do such a thing? It sounds like an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/) ;)

Comment: Hey @sp00m I just started a project where I have to do such thing.

Comment: @abarik I think @sp00m is asking you to add more detail to the question.  We need to know *why* your project wants to do this, so that we can make a sensible answer.  For instance, do you want to switch between TLS (`https://`) for different environments?

Comment: Hey @Davin I did it, I wrote this code in my controller and got it

Thanks for your response

Comment: @abarik It is OK to answer your own question.  So, instead of update the question, add an answer and mark it as correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got my answer here is the controller code

```
function ListCtrl($scope, $http,Project) {
  $http.get('/project').success(function(data){
   for(var i=0;i<data.length;i++){
   data[i].site=data[i].site.replace('http://','Hey');

 }
  $scope.projects=data;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

try this.
http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_replace.asp

```
var str = "Visit Microsoft!";
var res = str.replace("Microsoft", "W3Schools");
```